# Identify probability distribution

Tags: probability

How can  2 stock have different  Average return and different standard deviation and Still have the same probability distribution

Comment: @Stephan Unless I misread it, is this question not asking *exactly the opposite*? I think the answer is that the premise of this question is wrong - if they have different average and SD then they cannot have the same distribution!

Comment: @Silverfish: well, you are right. I should read things before acting. I retracted my close vote, so now I can't vote as "unclear what you are asking". Would you be so kind to do so?

Comment: @Stephan The author of the question has apparently agreed with the nomination, which might suggest the question has been mis-written! Not sure quite what to do with it now.